# C# compiler verbose output with CodeDomProvider

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, c#-4.0, compiler-errors

I have

```
CompilerResults cr = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, source);
//where source is an array of source file names
```

I want verbose output of the compile for each individual file.

Currently I am using a BackgroundWorker to compile and send back error messages, but this happens after the compile is complete. (Success/with errors.)

```
 foreach (CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
 {
       synchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((m) =>
       //pushCompilerMessage(currentWindow, msg)
             ), null);                     
 }
```

All this works fine, but how do pass these messages in such a way that it appears as though in true verbose mode?

Comment: @Hans: I mean like a step-by-step detailed output and yes in real-time..

Comment: @Hans: Eventually, I put `ReportProgress` to good use, thanks. I'll mark this as accepted if you'd like to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Verbose" doesn't make much sense here. Do you really mean "real time"? Use the BackgroundWorker's ReportProgress method.